# Can't create an index column in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I had previously created a table with multiple columns. Among them a *"message"* column of type `longtext`. I want to modify my table by creating an index for the `"message"` column. I changed my entity and lunched the command on my bash to update the table. Unfortunately, I got this error message.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE INDEX message_idx ON 
project (message)':SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'message' used in key specification without a key 
length
```

I want to point out that I had been looking for the method to do this kind of operation. And here's what I did on my side.

**The index:**

```
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="message_idx",columns={"message"},options={"length"=255})})
```

**The column:**

```
 /**
 * @var String $message
 * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text",length=255,nullable=true,options={"default": "NULL"})
 */
private $message;
```

Comment: I presume you simply can't define length for text indexes with doctrine annotations.

Comment: Yes @u_mulder..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="message_idx",columns={"message"}, options={"length": 255})})
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
    */
    private $message;

}
```

When you use a text type as index you need define a length and 'text' type doesn't have length, so you need use 'string' and length

[image]

Comment: In resume, the error is a MySQL error and not a Doctrine error.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Your solution works for me. Thank you @Cuchu